# Existence and uniqueness of solutions to the wave equation.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

Over the real line, I know that for initial data $u(0,x)=f(x)$ and $u_t(0,x)=g(x)$ s.t. $f,g\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ [name this (1)] we have uniqueness.
My question is:

> Without assuming (1), do we still have uniqueness? If not, can you give me a counterexample? In this setting, does D'Alembert's solution and that one obtained by separation of variables (Fourier method) coincide?

Also, in higher dimensions:

> On the existence in a bounded open subset $A\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ with regular $\partial A$: Is there any guarantee of the existence of solutions? If not, under what conditions on $A,f,g$ and boundary conditions do we guarantee existence?
>
> On the uniqueness over $\mathbb{R}^n$: What assumptions must be made in order to guarantee uniqueness to the wave equation solution over the whole space? Is there any? If not, could you give me a counterexample or an intuitive explanation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is (1) the assumption that $f,g\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$? What alternative assumptions on $f,g$ do you propose? And what is your notion of a solution then?

Comment: Yes, in order to have finite energy at $t=0$; another assumption might be $f,g$ with compact support for the same reason, but why is the uniqueness lost without any of these? Solution for me is a function $u(t,x)$ regular enough s.t. $u_{tt}=u_{xx}$ and the initial conditions are satisfied.